# Generating test data in R

Tags: r, testing, data.table

I am trying to generate this table as one of the inputs to a test.

```
        id                 diff          d
 1:      1                    2 2020-07-31
 2:      1                    1 2020-08-01
 3:      1                    1 2020-08-02
 4:      1                    1 2020-08-03
 5:      1                    1 2020-08-04
 6:      2                    2 2020-07-31
 7:      2                    1 2020-08-01
 8:      2                    1 2020-08-02
 9:      2                    1 2020-08-03
10:      2                    1 2020-08-04
11:      3                    2 2020-07-31
12:      3                    1 2020-08-01
13:      3                    1 2020-08-02
14:      3                    1 2020-08-03
15:      3                    1 2020-08-04
16:      4                    2 2020-07-31
17:      4                    1 2020-08-01
18:      4                    1 2020-08-02
19:      4                    1 2020-08-03
20:      4                    1 2020-08-04
21:      5                    2 2020-07-31
22:      5                    1 2020-08-01
23:      5                    1 2020-08-02
24:      5                    1 2020-08-03
25:      5                    1 2020-08-04
        id                 diff          d
```

I have done it like this -

```
input1 = data.table(id=as.character(1:5), diff=1)
input1 = input1[,.(d=seq(as.Date('2020-07-31'), by='days', length.out = 5)),.(id, diff)]
input1[d == '2020-07-31']$diff = 2
```

`diff` is basically the number of days to the next weekday. Eg. `31st Jul 2020` is `Friday`. Hence diff is 2 which is the diff to the next weekday, `Monday`. For the others it will be 1.

- Is there a more R idiomatic way of doing this ?

I personally dont like that I had to generate the date sequence for each of the ids separately or the hardcoding of the diff that I have to do in the input for 31st July. Is there a more generic way of doing this without the hardcoding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can create all combination of dates and `id` using `crossing` and create `diff` column based on whether the weekday is `"Friday"`.

```
library(dplyr)

tidyr::crossing(id = 1:5, d = seq(as.Date('2020-07-31'), 
                          by='days', length.out = 5)) %>%
    mutate(diff = as.integer(weekdays(d) == 'Friday') + 1)
```

Similar logic using base R `expand.grid` :

```
transform(expand.grid(id = 1:5, 
                      d = seq(as.Date('2020-07-31'), by='days', length.out = 5)), 
          diff = as.integer(weekdays(d) == 'Friday') + 1)
```

and `CJ` in `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
df <- CJ(id = 1:5, d = seq(as.Date('2020-07-31'), by='days', length.out = 5))
df[, diff := as.integer(weekdays(d) == 'Friday') + 1]
```

Comment: Thanks. The CJ worked. Out of curiosity I did a class(df) on the above output. It shows    `[1] "data.table" "data.frame"`. Why does it show both ?

Comment: You can have more than 1 class for an object and I think for `data.table` it always shows both of them.